# return all the docs where id is found mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

im trying to return an array of claims from my mongodb ,
but when im using the function its returns undefined ,
how can i return the results as array ?

i have been looking for many questions about this in stackoverflow but none of them works..
so please do not refer me to another question i saw every thing has possible searched over 10 combantions for answering that ..

```
module.exports = {
    getAllClaims: (userId)=>{

        let claims;
          Claim.find({'sender':userId}, function (err, docs) {
            if(err){
                claims = []
                console.log(err)
            }
            if(docs)
            {
                claims = docs;
                console.log('CLAIMS FOUND:',docs)
            }


        });
        return claims;
    }
}
```

and when i use it it returns undefined
i have checked already in my collections there is a claim with that id so why its returning an undefined ?

```
console.log(getAllClaims(55166212)) // undefined
```

this is my schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const claimSchema = new Schema({
    sender: Number,
    title: String,
    content: String,
    status:Number, // 0 unreaded,1 in process 2 completed.
    date: Date
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('claim', claimSchema, 'claims')
```

i have been trying that too but it returns an empty array , but when i log in the fun the doc is found , so why it dosent return it ?

```
var cls = [];
          Claim.find({'sender':userId}, function (err, docs) {
            if(err){
                //claims = []
                console.log(err)
            }
            if(docs)
            {
                docs.forEach(doc=>{
                    cls.push(doc)
                    console.log('DOC IS: ',doc)
                })
            }


        });
        return cls;
```

Comment: help please ???

Comment: It could be that the input `userId` will be coming in as a string

Answer (score 0):

Return the find promise in getAllClaims and use it with then.

```
return Claim.find({'sender':userId})
```

@

```
getAllClaims(userId).then(res => {
console.log(res);
})
```